# Is it possible to change the user/password inside the connectionString inside App.config programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connect_cbu" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.66.67; Initial Catalog=CBU; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=Admin;Password=1234"/>   
  </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Let's say that I define the following two strings: `public static string user;` and `public static string pass;` inside `Global.cs`. Is it possible to somehow include them in the `connectionString`?

Example:

```
connectionString="Data Source=192.168.66.67; Initial Catalog=CBU; Persist Security Info=True; User ID='Global.user';Password='Global.pass'"/>
```

**Solution, based on TheGeneral's answer:**

app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<clear/>
<add name="connect_cbu" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.66.67; Initial Catalog=CBU; Persist Security Info=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows;


namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            OpenConnection();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        public void OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                con.ConnectionString = BuildConnectionString("Admin", "1234"); 
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(this, "Do you want to exit?", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
            if (result != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        public static string BuildConnectionString(string userName, string userPassword)
        {
            ConnectionStringSettings settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect_cbu"];

            if (null != settings)
            {
                string connectString = settings.ConnectionString;
                Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", connectString);
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString)
                {
                    UserID = userName,
                    Password = userPassword
                };
                Console.WriteLine("Modified: {0}", builder.ConnectionString);
                return builder.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("App.config is missing!", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return "fail";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: I did. I wanted to programmatically change the username/password inside  the `connectionString` in `App.config`. It's two lines of code, but I'll add them if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are certain [Connection String Builders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-builders) that would probably be helpful for you

> If certain elements of a connection string are known beforehand, they
>   can be stored in a configuration file and retrieved at run time to
>   construct a complete connection string. For example, the name of the
>   database might be known in advance, but not the name of the server. Or
>   you might want a user to supply a name and password at run time
>   without being able to inject other values into the connection string.

**Eg**

```
<connectionStrings>  
  <clear/>  
  <add name="partialConnectString"   
    connectionString="Initial Catalog=Northwind;"  
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  
</connectionStrings>
```

**Example**

```
private static void BuildConnectionString(string dataSource,
    string userName, string userPassword)
{
    // Retrieve the partial connection string named databaseConnection
    // from the application's app.config or web.config file.
    ConnectionStringSettings settings =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["partialConnectString"];

    if (null != settings)
    {
        // Retrieve the partial connection string.
        string connectString = settings.ConnectionString;
        Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", connectString);

        // Create a new SqlConnectionStringBuilder based on the
        // partial connection string retrieved from the config file.
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder =
            new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);

        // Supply the additional values.
        builder.DataSource = dataSource;
        builder.UserID = userName;
        builder.Password = userPassword;
        Console.WriteLine("Modified: {0}", builder.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

> but how do I initialize the BuildConnectionString?

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(youCurrrentConnectionString);

builder.UserID = userName;
builder.Password = userPassword;


//usage 
ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: This is going to sound stupid, but how do I initialize the BuildConnectionString? `BuildConnectionString("Admin", "1234");` doesn't work - SQL exception returns "Login failed for user ''.

Answer (score 1):

App.Config is part of the software within the *Program Files* Folder it is not meant to be altered after Setup.

You also should not write username/passwords in there. It would be accessible for anyone to read.

Use *ConnectionStringBuilder* and store username/password in a secure place.

Or maybe if it is a MSSQL DB you can use *Integrated Security*. So DB access security could maybe be handled outside of your software.